# Why I cant declare a constant in a function?

Tags: c, constants

I am getting this error when I try to execute the following function
`src\main.c(41): error:  #259: constant value is not known`

The code:

```
uint8_t checksum_tx(uint64_t Data, uint8_t dataLength, uint8_t checksum_len )   {

  const uint8_t length = (dataLength + checksum_len - 1) / checksum_len;

    //** splitting data into 6-bits subunits . . .
    
    uint8_t res = 0U;   
    uint8_t dataSubUnit[length];
```

the line that causes the error
`const uint8_t length = (dataLength + checksum_len - 1) / checksum_len;`

could someone clarify what is going wrong?
I read somewhere the constants in C must be declared directly, it is not allowed to initialize them, I guess that is what I have done.

Comment: constants are evaluated during compilation time. In your case you are using function parameters to define it, but their value is unknown to the compiler

Comment: What compiler/OS are you using? In C17, a `const` variable is not a variable whose value is known at compile-time; instead, `const` basically means that its value may not be modified once it has been initialized. That's why the `dataSubUnit` will not be a static array, but it will be a VLA (i.e.: an array whose dimension is known at run-time, and that will be allocated on the stack), but not all compilers support VLAs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- We really need to know which compiler you're using. Standard compilers don't have problems with your initialized constant variable, even GCC with "-std=c90". Optimally [edit] your question and provide also a [example], with emphasis on "complete".

Comment: Please, try to post syntactically correct code, better if a complete example as recommended in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) So we don't need to correct the code to see what error the compiler produces (probably we get the error you made, or a different one, or none at all).  This means your function header must be separated from the body by a left curly brace, and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will try to post more comprehensible questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the language... or a feature (depends on who reads it) for the `const` tagged object.  I think your interpretation of the `const` keyword, applying to a data object with a limited life, should make it immutable for the life of the object, this is, the execution of the block in which it is defined.  But the compiler makes the data effectively a constant (like the constant PI) and it must hold the same value for the whole program life, and not on each function invocation.  In the case you post, the value of the expression that the constant will have is not known until the function is started and the parameters receive their values (only then can the initialization expression be evalutated), so the constant is not actually a constant (You could provide different values for the function parameters in different call and make the constant value different than in the previous call).

In java, for example, there's a `final` keyword to mark a data value as constant, and you must preserve (you are not allowed to assign/change values to it) during the life of the object (this meaning since it is created until it is destroyed), but the initial value is determined dynamically, at the time of creation.  This is not true in C.  A `const` declared data object must be actually a constant, and it must be initialized by an expression (called a const expression) whose value can be determined at compilation time.

Answer (score -2):

Constants are not real variables: once the code is compiled constants are translated into hard-coded values (immediate operands), or references within a section of the program that cannot be written (usually .rodata).

So, constants can't be assigned a value at run-time. You have to set a value that is known at compilation time, hence a value that does not depend on other variable(s). (e.g. `const int length = 42;` ).
If you cannot know the value of `length` before compiling the code, then you need a variable, not a `const`.

I guess you needed a constant to declare the array `dataSubUnit`. The usual way to solve this is to declare an array large enough to contain any possible `length`:

```
#define MAX_DATA_SUBUNIT_LEN 42

uint8_t checksum_tx(uint64_t Data, ... ) {
  uint8_t dataSubUnit[MAX_DATA_SUBUNIT_LEN];
```

... and to prevent a possible overflow:

```
uint8_t length = (dataLength + checksum_len - 1) / checksum_len;

if ( length < MAX_DATA_SUBUNIT_LEN ) {
   ... // proceed 
}
else {
    // return some relevant error code
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is completely wrong. In the first two paragraphs you are confusing `const` with `constexpr` (which by the way exists only in C++), and your proposed solution isn't very good; it's a workaround at best. But what if you ever need more than 42 elements in your array? The real solution is using `malloc` to create an array of the right size.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well, C compilers used to map 'const' symbols into the .rodata section and prevent any store operation there, or did that change while I wasn't looking?
Also, I agree that malloc() would be the most memory-efficient solution, but using dynamic allocations, or variable-length arrays, is sometimes forbidden by coding rules.

Comment: The common (not standardized!) .rodata sections includes only **static** constants. An automatic variable will not go there.

Comment: @fabiencasas: An environment where dynamic allocations are forbidden would be very specific indeed, and worthy of mention by the OP. Without any such constraints mentioned, it is safe to assume (IMHO) that `malloc()` is allowed.